# $facebook->getSession(); not working. No idea why?

Tags: php, facebook, graph

```
 <?php

require 'facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '130407366991766',
  'secret' => '****',
  'cookie' => true,
));

// We may or may not have this data based on a $_GET or $_COOKIE based session.
//
// If we get a session here, it means we found a correctly signed session using
// the Application Secret only Facebook and the Application know. We dont know
// if it is still valid until we make an API call using the session. A session
// can become invalid if it has already expired (should not be getting the
// session back in this case) or if the user logged out of Facebook.
$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
```

```
<h1><a href="example.php">php-sdk</a></h1>

<?php if ($me): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
  <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?=$loginUrl?>">
  <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
</a>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Session</h3>
<?php if ($me): ?>
<pre><?php print_r($session); ?></pre>

<h3>You</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $uid; ?>/picture">
<?php echo $me['name']; ?>

<h3>Your User Object</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($me); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
<strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Naitik</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
<?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
```

For some reason... although the login seems to be working perfectly, my script continuously states "You are not connected".

I can only assume it is a problem with my application setup. Anyone have any ideas?

Demo: http://gua.com/fb-api/

Comment: What does `error_log` do? No errors in the log?

Comment: I wish i could tell you - I am simply playing with example code. No idea where that would be logged.. *looking* sorry.

Comment: having looked it should print out errors essentially. no errors are being printed.

Comment: Add a print_r of $session regardless of the state of $me -- what do you get?

Comment: Give Agent Hawkins the right answer below.

Comment: my problem was calling $facebook->setSession($session,true) before $session = $facebook->getSession(); removing setSession fixed the problem

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. My whole app was broken because getSession() was no longer functioning.

I downloaded the latest version of the PHP SDK and used the example to initialize the user session.

Basically, the session is initialized as soon as you create the Facebook object. So from the example code, when you call.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '191149314281714',
  'secret' => '73b67bf1c825fa47efae70a46c18906b',
));
```

You already have a session. To get the user ID, you just call:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the result of that call is `0`, then the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Change to OAuth2 and GetSession not working download new base_facebook.php and facebook.php from developers PHP Sdk and replace login procedure to:

```
if( $userfb = $facebook->getUser() ){ 
   try{
        $UserProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
   }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $userfb      = null;
      $UserProfile = null;
}
```

Is work in my site the new version can't show a fb:login-button with perms parameter :( and i can't repair

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have changed the way you call the API and the old REST API calls are being depracated. This means that the getSession() method doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the Api Key to the constructor. Not the App Id.