# cant run facebook FQL twice: Requires user session thrown in - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

My facebook app has all of a sudden stopped working, I run this FQL once but if i try to run it twice it comes back with the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Requires user session thrown in
```

here's my function:

```
function get_top_fb_friends()
{
    require_once 'src/facebook.php';

    require('facebook_api_connect.php');

    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => 'SELECT uid, pic_square, name 
             FROM user 
             WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
             ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC','access_token'=>$accessToken);

    $friend_array = $facebook->api($params);

    return $friend_array;
}
```

I tried adding in the access token but it still fails the second time.

it seems to be the same problem as described here:

[FQL Error 102 Requires user session on a repeated query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734737/fql-error-102-requires-user-session-on-a-repeated-query)

im at a loss as to how to get it to work!

Comment: Debug the access token. My guess is that it isn't a user seesion

Comment: how do i get the user session? is it different to the access token? i looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128085/facebook-getsession-not-working-no-idea-why

Comment: The access token can be a user access token, a page access token or an app access token.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement Facebook Login, the Access Token you'll receive from

```
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

is very likely an App Access Token, which is not valid for requesting the kind of information you want. Also, you need the `user_friends` permission, and apparantly you're using an old version of the SDK, because `'method' => 'fql.query'` is outdated.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#read

Comment: i tried adding user_friends but it still doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be more specific. Did you check whether you only receive an App Access Token or a User Access Token? And, did you change the call as suggested?

Comment: i changed the scope by adding in user_friends but got the same outcome, the script works fine the first time after the user has logged in but if i run it again i get the error requires user session. im not sure about the app access token or user access token part how do i check the difference between them?

Comment: it looks like it is a application access token rather than a user access token, although it's a user access token the first time and a app access token the second time, i cant understand why the 2nd time it is run the GetAccessToken() function returns a app access token rather than a user access token

Comment: fixed it! my app was looping around on itself